# Increase Brightness and Contrast of image after capturing from camera in Android

Tags: android, pdf, camera, itext, brightness

I am making a one application in which I capture an image from camera and make the pdf out of it.

But the quality of image is poor. So I want to set the brightness and contrast of the image.

1. Is there any way to increase Brightness and Contrast of image after capturing from camera in Android?
2. After capturing the image when I cropped it and then display it in pdf, the lower part of the image has been cut.

For pdf usage in this application I have used iText.jar (5.0.6).

Comment: Could it be, you are scaling/positioning your image wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For having the full image displayed in the pdf generated, please try by applying **'scaleAbsolute'** to the image.

```
File newFile = new File(pdfPath);
newFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfFile);
ocument.open();

Rectangle rectangle = document.getPageSize();
Image image = Image.getInstance(imagePath);

image.scaleAbsolute((rectangle.getWidth() - 75.0f),
                    (rectangle.getHeight() - 75.0f));
```